# clickable link in chat box in android using xmpp

Tags: android, hyperlink, xmpp, chat, clickable

We are building a chat app using XMPP. This is an android based application.
Chat is working fine but if I send a link then its not clickable in the chat window.
In android application, I take data from an EditText and then send it using XMPP.

I have searched a lot but did not find any related query. Most of queries are related to 
making link clickable in TextView.

Appreciate help and any pointers.

Thanks,
Satendra

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using the property android:autoLink="web" of TextView.